# React - delete button deletes correct entry but visually removes bottom row

Tags: reactjs

From reading previous SO posts and blogs I'm not sure if this is related to props. Either way I'm baffled.

I have a class component, responsible for loading data, which uses a functional component for displaying the data. When the delete button, in the functional component, is pressed it calls `props.onDelete` which does a `fetch` and reloads the data. The correct row is deleted from the DB but in the browser it's always the bottom row which is removed. On reloading the page the correct data is displayed.

I've put a breakpoint in the functional component and in the class component `render` and `loadStations` methods. On clicking delete button I can see that `loadStations` is called (which calls `setState`) and then the functional component is called. However, the `render` method is never called.

Stations.js (the class component parent)

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import EditableTable from "../util/EditableTable";

// column definitions
const columns = [
    ...
]

export default class Stations extends Component {

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            stations: []
        };
    }

    componentDidMount () {
        this.loadStations();
    }

    loadStations() {
        fetch(`/api/stations`)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(response => {
            this.setState({
                stations: response.data
            })
        });
    }

    saveStation = (e, station) => {
        ...
    }
    
    deleteStation = (e, dataRowIdx) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        var stationId = this.state.stations[dataRowIdx].stationId;

        fetch(`/api/station/${stationId}`, {
            method: "DELETE"
        })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            if (data.error) {
                this.setState({ error: data.error });
            } else {
                this.loadStations();
            }
        }).catch(error => {
            this.setState({
                error: error.message
            });
        });
    }

    render() {

return (
<div>
    <h4>Stations</h4>

    <EditableTable
        columns={columns}
        data={this.state.stations}
        onDelete={this.deleteStation}
        onChanged={this.saveStation}
    ></EditableTable>
</div>
        );
    }
}
```

EditableTable.js (the functional component)

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import EditableLabel from "./EditableLabel";

export default function Table(props) {

    var emptyDataRow = {};
    props.columns.forEach( (column) => {
        emptyDataRow[column.property] = ""
    });
    const [newRowState, setNewRowState] = useState(emptyDataRow);

    function cellChanged(e, value, dataRowIdx, columnProperty) {
        var dataRow = props.data[dataRowIdx];
        dataRow[columnProperty] = value;
        props.onChanged(e, dataRow);
    }

    return <table>
        <thead>
        <tr>
        {props.columns.map( (column, idx) =>
            <th key={idx} value>{column.label}</th>
        )}
            <th></th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        {props.data.map( (dataRow, dataRowIndex) =>
            <tr key={dataRowIndex}>
            {props.columns.map( (column, columnIndex) =>
                <td key={columnIndex}>
                    <EditableLabel
                        value={dataRow[column.property]}
                        column={column}
                        onChanged={(e, newValue) => { cellChanged(e, newValue, dataRowIndex, column.property); }}
                    ></EditableLabel>
                </td>
            )}
                <td><button onClick={(e) => { props.onDelete(e, dataRowIndex); }}>delete</button></td>
            </tr>
        )}
            
        </tbody>
    </table>
}
```

Comment: Having looked that hard at the code, but I see you  use `idx` as the key. If your list is dynamic then you can't use `index` as the `key` value. Otherwise you'll get the bug you're seeing now. Set the `key` property to a something which uniquely identifies that row/column/cell/whatever. If there isn't one, make one. If you do some Googling around what the key prop actually is and how it works, as well as why not to use index as key there's a bunch of tutorials and SO posts and such already out there, they should help explain this in detail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is most likely because you are using the `index` given by the `map` method as the key.
This just uses the item's location in the array as the key, which will not be a sufficient identifier if something in the middle of the array has been removed.

You should give a `key` that is identifiably unique for that item in the array, eg an unchanging ID or name.

Comment: Cheers. And thanks Jayce444. I'm even more baffled why a search on SO didn't give me this answer :)